# How to bypass self implemented mouseClicked Event in Java

Tags: java, swing, mouseclick-event

I am working on a big Gui project. Lots off complex stuff has been done and I cannot change the structure of the code. And as it is a complex project it is difficult to explain or give an SSE but I will try my best.

In our project some people have implemented their own Table. All the cells int the table are a class called CellPanel which extends `JPanel` class. So all table cells are `JPanels` actually. And these crazy guys have implemented their own mouseClicked function which is about 400 lines. So I am not pasting it here for the good of everyone :) But that `mouseClicked` method only works if it is a right click. SO I have the chance of doing something like this:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    DropTable.selectedColorMng(rowInTable);
    if(e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        System.out.println("left click");
    }
    else{ 
        // 400 lines of code here
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is that these CellPanels are designed to contain a label and an icon. It has always been used like this. No dynamic content inside. But now we have a requirement and I have modified these CellPanels to contain `JList` in a `ScrollPane`. But these `JLists` are not clickable. I want to scroll them make multiple selections, but they do not respond to my left clicks. So I think I have to fill inside the if statement of the above code.

But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question completely. I understood, that your `CellPanel` catches the click events so that they doesn't reach the `JList` which is contained in the `CellPanel`.

If it is like that you can simply delegate that event in the `mouseClick` of the `CellPanel` to the `JList` there must be a reference to it as it is shown in there.